# プログラムが意図しない終了方法をした時の、socketのclose()について

Tags: python, network, socket, udp

以下のようにPythonを使って、一定間隔でUDP通信するプログラムを書いています。

GUIの右上の閉じるボタンを押してプログラムを終了させた場合、スレッドは
`self.thread.setDaemon(True)` によって終了するのですが、socketは `close()` されないまま終わってしまっています。(Stopボタンを押した場合はsocketはclose()されます)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このように `close()` されずにプログラムが終了した場合、どのような問題がありますか？
また、右上の閉じるボタンでプログラムを終了した場合でもsocketを `close()` するにはどうしたらよいですか？

---

**ソースコード**

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
from socket import socket, AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,SOCK_STREAM

class threading_and_sleepGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop_flag=False
        self.thread=None
        self.s = None

    def worker(self):
        msg = "test"
        self.s.sendto(msg.encode(), ("127.0.0.1", 8888))
        time.sleep(8)

    def scheduler(self,interval, f, wait = True):
        base_time = time.time()
        next_time = 0
        while not self.stop_flag:
            t = threading.Thread(target = f)
            t.start()
            if wait:
                t.join()
            next_time = ((base_time - time.time()) % interval) or interval
            time.sleep(next_time)

    def start(self):
        if not self.thread:
            self.s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
            self.s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)

            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.scheduler, args=(1, self.worker, False))
            self.thread.setDaemon(True)
            self.stop_flag=False
            self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.thread:
            self.s.close()
            self.stop_flag=True
            self.thread.join()
            self.thread=None

    def GUI_start(self):
        root=tk.Tk()
        Button001=tk.Button(root,text="Start",command=self.start)
        Button001.pack()
        Button002=tk.Button(root,text="Stop",command=self.stop)
        Button002.pack()
        root.mainloop()

t = threading_and_sleepGUI()
t.GUI_start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

プログラム（プロセス）が終了したら、そこで使われていたソケットなどはcloseされますから、心配いりません。
パケットが届かない可能性があるUDP通信ですから、受信側にも影響ないです。

Answer (score 2):

@Fumu 7 さん回答のように、ソケットやファイル等の資源についてはcloseされるとしても、何かしらの後始末はやっておきたい場合は、[root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#protocols) を使ってイベントハンドラを登録しておくと、それが呼ばれるようです。

ただし.afterで周期的に(多分マルチスレッドでの処理も含んで)何かしている場合は、処理ループの実行中でもそれが呼び出されるので、単純に終了処理`destroy()`を呼ぶのは不味くて、フラグを立ててループを終了するなど、後始末は工夫しましょう、という回答が以下の記事にあるようです。
[How do I handle the window close event in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111155/9014308)

Upvoteは無いですが、こちらの回答ですね。
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58469034/9014308